# AS3 How to add event listener in Class A by using Class B and remove the same event using Class C?

Tags: actionscript-3, listener

This is AS3 question. 
I have Class "addadd", "Symbol1"(Button1), "Symbol2"(Button2). 
In "addadd" I have 3 functions. Function "StanishevFadd" creates object and add Event Listener, function "stanishevFremove" removes Event Listener and function "frameDOstanishev" that will be triggered when the event is added.
So, I obviously want to trigger the event from Symbol1 and stop the same event from Symbol2. Unfortunately doesn't work this way. I am totally confuzed. For example if I want to add and remove the event listener from Symbol1 only - YES works, but I am not able to create event from Symbol1 and remove the same event from Symbol2 in class addadd. Please help guys, please!

```
public class addadd
{
    var stanishev:stanishev_line = new stanishev_line;

    public function addadd()
    {
    }

    public function stanishevFadd()
    {
        Main.display.addChild(stanishev);
        stanishev.gotoAndPlay("start");
        stanishev.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameDOstanishev);
    }

    public function stanishevFremove()
    {
        stanishev.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameDOstanishev);
    }

    public function frameDOstanishev(e:Event)
    {
        trace (stanishev.currentFrame);
    }
}
```

//------------------------------

```
public class Symbol1 extends SimpleButton
{
    var call_creator:addadd = new addadd;

    public function Symbol1()
    {
        // constructor code
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, eventResponse);
    }

    function eventResponse(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        call_creator.stanishevFadd();
    }
}
```

//----------------------

```
    public class Symbol2 extends SimpleButton
{
    var call_creator:addadd = new addadd;

    public function Symbol2()
    {
        // constructor code
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, eventResponse2);
    }

    function eventResponse2(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        call_creator.stanishevFremove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your design as it stands has bigger problems than just the question you asked. IMO, the best answer is to tell you how to completely redesign the whole thing, but I'm not going to invest the time in typing up that answer unless you're open to it. Are you?

Comment: I will be pleased if you tell me how to redesign this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I am not sure what the overall purpose of this whole thing, so I am going to call this thing OddView. I'm going to try to get close to what it looks like you are trying to do in a more OO way.

I believe it should be possible for you to encapsulate all of this behavior without involving your Main Class, and there are a lot of reasons not to involve it, especially [not with static variables](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/) like you're doing.

```
public class OddView extends Sprite {
   protected var _btn1:SimpleButton;
   protected var _btn2:SimpleButton;
   protected var _stanishev:StanishevLine;//note I changed your Class name to be more in line with AS3 standards

   public function OddView() {
      super();
   }
   public function get btn1():SimpleButton {
       return _btn1;
   }
   public function set btn1(value:SimpleButton):void {
      if (value != _btn1) {
          if (_btn1) {
              removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, goToState2);
          }
          _btn1 = value;
          if (_btn1) {
              _btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, goToState2);
          }
      }
   }
   public function get btn2():SimpleButton {
       return _btn2;
   }
   public function set btn2(value:SimpleButton):void {
      if (value != _btn2) {
          if (_btn2) {
              removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, goToState1);
          }
          _btn2 = value;
          if (_btn2) {
              _btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, goToState1);
          }
      }
   }
   public function get stanishev():StanishevLine {
       return _stanishev;
   }
   public function set stanishev(value:StanishevLine):void {
       if (value != _stanishev) {
           if (_stanishev) {
              cleanUp(null);
           }
           _stanishev = value;
           initStanishev();
       }
   }
   public function initStanishev():void {
      if (_stanishev) {
         _stanishev.visible = true;
         _stanishev.goToAndPlay('start');
         addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, showStanishevFrame);
         addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, cleanUp);
      }
   }
   public function goToState1(e:Event) :void {
       goToAndStop(1);
   }
   public function goToState2(e:Event):void {
       goToAndStop('State2');
   }
   public function showStanishevFrame(e:Event):void {
       if (stanishev) {
          trace('current frame', stanishev.currentFrame);
       }
   }
   public function cleanUp(e:Event):void {
      removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, showStanishevFrame);
      removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, cleanUp);
   }
}
```

Note that I'm assuming that you're going to apply OddView as the Base Class of a library symbol. I'm *not* including any instantiation or positioning logic, since I tend to [use the stage for those things](http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html).

Note that the reason I check for existence on the stage instances is that it is theoretically possible for someone to assign OddView as the Base Class and not put a btn1, btn2, or stanishev on the stage of that library symbol.

However, this Class is written assuming you're going to handle the visual parts of those 3 items by placing btn1, btn2, and stanishev on the stage where you want them to be.

Also note that I strongly suspect that most of this is completely unnecessary. It's quite possible that you could handle most of this by simply using the over state of btn1. However, that doesn't completely account for why you want to *only* remove the event listener and take no other action when btn2 is cicked. So I went for "overkill" in the absence of real info about what you're actually trying to accomplish.

**Note on the edits**
Note what I'm doing there in the setter--if there was already a value stored, we remove the listeners that were on that old, outgoing, listener. Then if the incoming value is not null, we add the new listener.

I still suspect you don't need to do so much, but considering the information you *have* provided, this should help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks thanks Amy.
You are great.
now I am going to spell out your code :). It's look more tidy :). I am very very new in AS3 and I still love it :)

Comment: To be honest I think my biggest challenge to learn this language is going to be the eventListener process and also the hierarchy

Comment: In my real project I use btn1 to move from frame1 to frame2 in timeline creating Stanishev obj and addevents. Btn2 is on frame2 and it move the timeline back to frame1 removing stanishev and all the events. I am doing this because I had so many problems (error:1009) moving between frames after activated eventListeners. I was about to finish the game 2 times but this error 1009 made me crazy. So I decided to remove all the listeners I don't use before I go to another frame in main timeline. I hope this is the right logic ...

Comment: What I did won't work for that. I deliberately extended Sprite so as not to have to use setters to manage the buttons. I'll edit to suit.

Comment: Following the logic I mentioned I created a class that can create and remove events and I intended to call the class if I want to add or remove an event. I was thinking I can work on one event from different objects but I was wrong. I also thought that this is more organize way to work with the events. ..well, I was wrong anyway . Thanks for your answers Amy

Comment: You can remove an event listener from a different object, but the object that removes the event listener has to know what the object is that added it (and what method was added). Because of this, in most instances it doesn't make sense to do it.

Comment: how to tell the object that removes the listener what is the object that created it? Is that because the new click event from btn2 creates new event object that is send to the target and basically the new event object is trying to kill itself not the created event object that already exists from btn1.

Comment: You shouldn't tell it this under most circumstances, as it violates encapsulation and likely Single Responsibility Principle. You should be able to do what you want with some variant of the code above (which doesn't require that). If that code doesn't meet your needs, you need to get more specific about what they are.

Comment: Thanks Amy. You gave me lots of information. I feel like my head is going to burst :). Have a great day and all the best

Answer (score 0):

You could make the variable `stanishev` in you `addadd` class a static variable. However I would not recommend doing this, one reason being you can only have one instance of `stanishev`. Hopefully @Amy Blankenship will tell you how to completely redesign your program, because it needs to be redesigned. This approach will work though, you should also add conditionals to the functions that add and remove eventListeners to `stanishev` to see if `stanishev` already has an eventlistener or does not have one.

```
public class addadd
{
public static var stanishev:stanishev_line = new stanishev_line;

public function addadd()
{
}

public function stanishevFadd()
{
    Main.display.addChild(stanishev);
    stanishev.gotoAndPlay("start");
    stanishev.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameDOstanishev);
}

public function stanishevFremove()
{
    stanishev.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameDOstanishev);
}

public function frameDOstanishev(e:Event)
{
    trace (stanishev.currentFrame);
}
}
```

```
public class Symbol1 extends SimpleButton
{

public function Symbol1()
{
    // constructor code
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, eventResponse);
}

function eventResponse(e:MouseEvent)
{
    addadd.stanishev.stanishevFadd();
}
}
```

```
public class Symbol2 extends SimpleButton
{

public function Symbol2()
{
    // constructor code
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, eventResponse2);
}

function eventResponse2(e:MouseEvent)
{
    addadd.stanishev.stanishevFremove();
}
}
```